# Core Data Migration using magical record

Tags: ios, core-data, migration, magicalrecord, core-data-migration

I have published my app in the store. Initially, there was no use of CoreData in the app as it was simple. Now I have to persist the data using it. My released app has xcdatamodel in it but there is no entity, its empty. Now as I am going to add new entities in it, will my new release cause issue for those users who have already installed my app from app store?

Do I need to create a new model version, in case if my previous version had no entities?

Also I am going to user MagicalRecord. Does setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed method is sufficient to perform migration?

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned

```
setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed
```

should be sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, this single line "setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed
" did the magic. No need to version datamodel.

Comment: I added "setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed", then I made changes to data model, added entity, deleted few and continued doing this experiment. What I found was the data is migrating and there is no crash. The data stored in original model is still there after updating the model without doing versioning. Is this correct way?

Comment: Sure - is that not what you expected?

Comment: Yeah, I wanted my app not to crash and no lose of user data. I ran couple of experiment and things seem to go as expected. What I have doubt is do we need to create newer version of model each time we make changes? Here in my case things seem to work without versioning.